# Issue with WMI File Watcher Path on the Network

Tags: sql-server, ssis, wmi-query

I am trying to get the right path on our network when using the WMI file watcher but keep getting error.  Initially, I was using a sample path that I found from online but now it is not letting me using the correct path.  Here is what I did for my testing initially:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA "CIM_DirectoryContainsFile"
AND TargetInstance.GroupComponent = "Win32_Directory.Name=\"C:\\\\NewFiles\""
```

but now my entire path should be as following:

```
\\dkk-exoon-1\ndata009\KLM\Projects\MYFILES
```

so how can I use my actual path?

Comment: can someone help?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to map that network share to a drive with NET USE command